# Series expansion of $1/(1+z^2)$ about the point I

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, power-series

I am trying to find a series representation for the complex function: $1/(1+z^2)$.
The text I am reading gives: $1/(1+z^2) = 1/((z+I)(z-I)) = -I/(2(z-I)) +1/4 - I(z-I)/8 - (z-I)^2/16 + ...$

I do not know how to derive this series.

Comment: Is I the imaginary unit i.e. I^2=-1?

Comment: Yes, I is the imaginary unit..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For clarity put $w=z-i$. Then $$\frac{1}{1+z^2}=\frac{1}{w(w+2i)}=-\frac{i}{2w}\frac{1}{1-\frac{iw}{2}}$$ Now use the familiar expansion $$\frac{1}{1-\frac{iw}{2}}=1+i\frac{w}{2}-\frac{w^2}{4}-i\frac{w^3}{8}+\dots$$ to get $$-\frac{i}{2w}+\frac{1}{4}+i\frac{w}{8}-\frac{w^2}{16}-i\frac{w^3}{32}+\frac{w^4}{64}+i\frac{w^5}{128}-\dots$$

Comment: I don't see how you went from the second expression to  the third.  I know that -I = 1/I .

Comment: Sorry, that was an error, I dropped an $i$. I hope that is fixed.

Comment: I think it should say -I/(2 w(1 + w/(2I)).

Comment: Yes, you can write it as either $1-\frac{iw}{2}$ or $1+\frac{w}{2i}$